# Upload in MVC 5 doesn't work with server but work locally in vs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I 'm trying to upload a file to a server, my web site is created with MVC 5. When I use visual studio on my computer and all database and foot folder are local files uploaded successfully but when I try to upload to a server files don't upload.

My view is:

```html
<form action="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-default" />
     @ViewBag.Path
</form>
```

And controller is:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["path"] = "";
    if (file == null )
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/attachments/"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        pathFile = path;
        ViewBag.Path = path;
    }
    return View("Create");
}
```

Upload in MVC 5 doesn't work with server but work locally in VS.
My code is correct because it work locally and my connection to server also is correct because I edit and create record in database inside server by web.

Comment: Can you describe the exception you get? And when it occurs?

Comment: What is not working. Are you even hitting the method? (you should always use the HtmlHelper methods to generate your controls, in particular use `Html.BeginForm()` so you `action` attribute is correctly generated

Comment: I bet is caused by wrong permissions in attachments folder...

Comment: Hi  Stephen Muecke,Thank you so much my problem base on WindowsHostingASP.NET's  guide and your guide was solved I grant to IIS_IUsrs   permission  of attachments folder  in security   tab , so code worked in server

Acutally I have some problems in mvc, I really appreciate you if I will be allowed to ask you a few question although I put my question in forums but almost I can't get answer If it possible my email is :

tomasanderson03@gmail.com

I want to ask some questions that i have about dropdownList in mvc and about  exporting  data to a word doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much my problem base on freinds guide   was solved and  problem was in attachment folder security  I grant to IIS_IUsrs   permission  of attachments folder  in security   tab , so code worked in server
best reagards
tomas